# Different result after using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

guys:

I am new to the use of python multiprocessing. Recently my research needs calculation with many iterations. So I tried to use multiprocessing to speed it up. But when I wrote a small sample code, I found that the curve I got with multiprocessing is different from that without multiprocessing.

The code with multiprocessing:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

class Classic:
    def __init__(self,position,type):
        assert type == 'A' or type == 'B'    
        self.position = position
        self.type = type
    def getposition(self):
        return self.position
    def gettype (self):
        return self.type
    def setposition(self,pos):
        self.position = pos
    def settype (self,t):
        self.type = t
def number_count(system):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(0,len(system)):
        if system[i] !=0:
            counter=counter+1
    return counter
def time_evolution(system_temp,steps):
    numberlist=np.zeros(steps)
    number = number_count(system_temp)
    for t in range(0,steps):
        for i in range(0,len(system_temp)):
            x = random.randint(0, len(system_temp)-2)
            if system_temp[x]!=0 and system_temp[x+1]!=0:
                p1 = system_temp[x]
                p2 = system_temp[x+1]
                p1_type = p1.gettype()
                p2_type = p2.gettype()
                exchange_check = random.randint(0,1)
                if p1_type == p2_type:
                    system_temp[x]=0
                    system_temp[x+1]=0
                    number = number-2
                elif exchange_check == 1:
                    type_temp = p1_type
                    p1.settype(p2_type)
                    p2.settype(type_temp)
            elif system_temp[x]!=0 and system_temp[x+1]==0:
                system_temp[x+1] = system_temp[x]
                system_temp[x] =0
            elif system_temp[x]==0 and system_temp[x+1]!=0:
                system_temp[x]=system_temp[x+1]
                system_temp[x+1]=0
        numberlist[t]=numberlist[t]+number
    return numberlist

if __name__ =='__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(8)
    size = 10000
    system_init = [0]*size
    particle_num = 3000
    repeat = 20
    steps = 2000
    res=[]
    totalnum= np.zeros(steps)
    randomlist = random.sample(range(1,100*repeat),repeat)
    for i in range(0,particle_num):
        pos = random.randint(0,size-1)
        ran_num = random.randint (0,1)
        if ran_num == 0:
            temp_type = 'A'
        else:
            temp_type = 'B'
        if system_init[pos] ==0:
            system_init[pos] = Classic(pos,temp_type)
    for k in range(0, repeat):
        system_temp = system_init[:]
        random.seed(randomlist[k])
        res.append(pool.apply_async(time_evolution, args=(system_temp,steps,)))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    for count in range(0,len(res)):
        totalnum =totalnum+ np.array(res[count].get())
    time=np.linspace(1,steps+1,steps)
    time_sqrt=np.sqrt(8.0*math.pi*time)
    density =totalnum/(repeat*size)
    density_mod = np.multiply(time_sqrt,density)
    #plt.loglog(time,density_mod)
    #plt.savefig("modified_density_loglog.pdf")
    #plt.close()
    myfile=open('density_mod2.txt','w')
    for element in density_mod:
        myfile.write(str(element))
        myfile.write('\n')
    myfile.close()
```

And the code without multiprocessing is

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np
class Classic:
    def __init__(self,position,type):
        assert type == 'A' or type == 'B'    
        self.position = position
        self.type = type
    def getposition(self):
        return self.position
    def gettype (self):
        return self.type
    def setposition(self,pos):
        self.position = pos
    def settype (self,t):
        self.type = t
def number_count(system):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(0,len(system)):
        if system[i] !=0:
            counter=counter+1
    return counter    

def time_evolution(system_temp,steps):
    numberlist=np.zeros(steps)
    number = number_count(system_temp)
    for t in range(0,steps):
        for i in range(0,len(system_temp)):
            x = random.randint(0, len(system_temp)-2)
            if system_temp[x]!=0 and system_temp[x+1]!=0:
                p1 = system_temp[x]
                p2 = system_temp[x+1]
                p1_type = p1.gettype()
                p2_type = p2.gettype()
                exchange_check = random.randint(0,1)
                if p1_type == p2_type:
                    system_temp[x]=0
                    system_temp[x+1]=0
                    number = number-2
                elif exchange_check == 1:
                    type_temp = p1_type
                    p1.settype(p2_type)
                    p2.settype(type_temp)
            elif system_temp[x]!=0 and system_temp[x+1]==0:
                system_temp[x+1] = system_temp[x]
                system_temp[x] =0
            elif system_temp[x]==0 and system_temp[x+1]!=0:
                system_temp[x]=system_temp[x+1]
                system_temp[x+1]=0
        numberlist[t]=numberlist[t]+number
    return numberlist

size = 10000
system_init = [0]*size
particle_num = 3000
repeat = 20
steps = 2000
res=[]
totalnum= np.zeros(steps)
randomlist = random.sample(range(1,100*repeat),repeat)
for i in range(0,particle_num):
    pos = random.randint(0,size-1)
    ran_num = random.randint (0,1)
    if ran_num == 0:
        temp_type = 'A'
    else:
        temp_type = 'B'
    if system_init[pos] ==0:
        system_init[pos] = Classic(pos,temp_type)
for k in range(0, repeat):
    system_temp = system_init[:]
    random.seed(randomlist[k])
    res.append(time_evolution(system_temp,steps))

for count in range(0,len(res)):
    totalnum +=res[count]
time=np.linspace(1,steps+1,steps)
time_sqrt=np.sqrt(8.0*math.pi*time)
density =totalnum/(repeat*size)
density_mod = np.multiply(time_sqrt,density)
myfile=open('density_mod3.txt','w')
for element in density_mod:
    myfile.write(str(element))
    myfile.write('\n')
myfile.close()
```

And the result is shown as

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMblu.jpg)

The blue curve is result with multiprocessing and the orange one is that without multiprocessing. I am not sure why this would happen. How to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that you don't initialize the random number generator correctly. You have to do that "inside" the spawned processes.

Check the following simple example:

```
import random
import multiprocessing as mp

def rand_test_1():
    print(random.randint(0, 100))
    return None

def rand_test_2(seed):
    random.seed(seed)
    print(random.randint(0, 100))
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':

    repeat = 3
    randomlist = random.sample(range(1, 100 * repeat), repeat)

    print('Classic:')
    for k in range(repeat):
        random.seed(randomlist[k])
        rand_test_1()

    print('\nMultiprocessing version 1:')
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        for k in range(repeat):
            random.seed(randomlist[k])
            pool.apply_async(rand_test_1, args=tuple())
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    print('\nMultiprocessing version 2:')
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        for k in range(repeat):
            pool.apply_async(rand_test_2, args=(randomlist[k],))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

The results look like:

```
Classic:
32
78
6

Multiprocessing version 1:
84
43
90

Multiprocessing version 2:
32
78
6
```

You are using the multiprocessing version 1, I think you should use version 2.

One other point which has nothing to do with your problem: My impression is that it might be a good idea to use `.map`/`.starmap` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing%20pool%20pool%20map#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map)) instead of `.apply_async`:

```
    ...
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        res = list(pool.map(rand_test_2, randomlist))
```